# How to read line by line by using FileReader

Tags: java, swing, filereader, readfile

Thank you for your attention.

I have created a program which I'm using a Login form and Register form. 
Once users register their email and their password will be saved it into `submit.txt`. Then they will turn back to login form and enter their email and password which are saved into `submit.txt`.

In my code, I'm using write file for Register form, and Read file for Login Form. But, it doesn't work. I know my problem in the code used for Read File. May you help me to realize that?.

Thank you too much for your help.

```
 if (checkPassword(usern, hash)) {
    System.out.println("Logged in!");
    ChooseWindow ptb = new ChooseWindow();
    ptb.setVisible(true);
    LoginWindow.this.dispose();
 } else {
    System.out.println("Wrong password");
 }

 public boolean checkPassword(String username, String pass) {
    try {
        FileReader inFile = new  FileReader("/users/Ender/Desktop/GetUser/submit.txt");
        BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(inFile);
        String inString;

        while ((inString = inStream.readLine()) != null) {}
        inStream.close();                       
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem. Tell us what is wrong with the code (throws exception, does not compile, always returns false, ...). One problem I see is that you read all lines `while ((inString = inStream.readLine()) != null) {    }` but don't do anything with them. So `checkPassword` always returns false;

Comment: My problem is, It could not check the email or password which are entered in submit.txt. I know I'm getting stuck with the code in while{.....}. May you help me ?.

Comment: How are username and hash stored in the file you are reading? If it is like "username hash" in one line you could use `String usernameHash[] = inString.split(" ");` to split your line and then compare username to `usernameHash[0]` and hash to `usernameHash[1]`. If your format is different you might adjust this idea to your file.

Comment: here is my code as your advices. It debuggs those values in text file, But some of problems here I dont know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

here is my code to read from a file :

```
 String line;

    try {

        BufferedReader bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\ahmad\\Desktop\\aaa.TXT"));


        while ((line = bufferreader.readLine()) != null) {     
          /** 
            Your implementation  
          **/

        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help. So, my function has 2 variables ( username and pass ), so Do I have to do with it in while loop? ( some how to read and check them ) ..

Comment: This solution is invalid. You are reading the lines using BufferedReader, not FileReader.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we have a file with `username` and `hash` stored as follows:

> Hello World
>   Test Test
>   DumbUser 12345
>   User sjklfashm-0998()*(*&

and we want to use the first word in every line as `username` and the second as `password`/`hash`. Then the idea is:

- Read a line
- Split the line into parts at " "
- Compare the first part to `username` and the second to `pass`
- If there is a match return true, else start over

Which results in this code:

```
public boolean checkPassword(String username, String pass) {
    // if there is no username or no password you can not log in
    if(username == null || pass == null){ // diff
        return false;                     // diff
    }                                     // diff
    try {
        FileReader inFile = new  FileReader(PASSWORD_FILE);
        BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(inFile);
        String inString;

        while ((inString = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
            // we split every line into two parts separated by a space " "
            String usernameHash[] = inString.split(" "); // diff
            // if there are more or less than two parts this line is corrupted and useless
            if(usernameHash.length == 2                  // diff
                    && username.equals(usernameHash[0])  // diff
                    && pass.equals(usernameHash[1])){    // diff
                // if username matches the first part and hash the second everything is goo
                return true;                             // diff
            }                                            // diff
        }
        inStream.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

I marked the parts where my code differs from yours with `// diff`

Answer (score 1):

```
 try {
        FileReader inFile = new  FileReader("/users/Ender/Desktop/GetUser/submit.txt");
        BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(inFile);
        List<String> lines = inStream.Lines().toList();
        String username=lines[0];
        String password=lines[1];    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file using following code..

```
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./users/Ender/Desktop/GetUser/submit.txt"));
        String line;

        while ((line = bufferreader.readLine()) != null) {
            // line variable contains the readed line
            // You can append it to another String to get the whole text or anything you like
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If you want to write file use following code..

```
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("./users/Ender/Desktop/GetUser/submit.txt")); 
    writer.write(your_text);
    writer.close();
```

If you want to append text use following code to create the instance of `BufferedWriter`

```
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/users/Ender/Desktop/GetUser/submit.txt", true));
```